# What is the name of the technique for showing that $\mathbb{N}^2$ is countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

In order to show that $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is countable, we can define a bijection $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ like this one:

- $0 \rightarrow (0, 0)$
- $1 \rightarrow (1, 0)$
- $2 \rightarrow (0, 1)$
- $3 \rightarrow (2, 0)$
- $4 \rightarrow (1, 1)$
- $5 \rightarrow (0, 2)$
- $6 \rightarrow (3, 0)$
- $7 \rightarrow (2, 1)$
- $8 \rightarrow (1, 2)$
- ...

I need to prove that a set is countable, I know how to use this proof method, but I can't remember its name. Any hints?

Comment: You are just establishing a bijection between $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}$. You can call this enumeration of $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: fixed that

Comment: @baharampuri: in my context this is only one of a few possible enumerations. This is why I needed a name for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aha, I found it! The $f$ function I'm using is [Cantor's pairing function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function).